# Issue animating left property using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/cyFLh/1/), but I am not able to animate the `left` property of the `ul` using jQuery.

Here is the code I have:

```
 <style>
 .well{ overflow:hidden; }
  ul{width:22222px;}
  li + li{margin-left:.06%}
 </style>

<div class="container">
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-default leftslide">Left</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default rightslide">Right</button>
</div>
<div class="well"> 
 <ul class="list-inline">
   <li><img src="http://placehold.it/150X100" class="img-thumbnail"></li>
   <li><img src="http://placehold.it/150X100" class="img-thumbnail"></li>
   <li><img src="http://placehold.it/150X100" class="img-thumbnail"></li>
   <li><img src="http://placehold.it/150X100" class="img-thumbnail"></li>
   <li><img src="http://placehold.it/150X100" class="img-thumbnail"></li>
   <li><img src="http://placehold.it/150X100" class="img-thumbnail"></li>
   <li><img src="http://placehold.it/150X100" class="img-thumbnail"></li>
   <li><img src="http://placehold.it/150X100" class="img-thumbnail"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>


<script>
$(".leftslide").on("click",function(){
  $(".list-inline").animate({left:'-250px'}, 300);   
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`left` doesn't mean anything unless you tell it how to interpret the `position`. `relative` to my current location? As `absolute` coordinates? `fixed` in the viewport?

Comment: Thanks harbichidian, I understand about Position relative but can you please let me know how an absolute and fixed may work in this specific example?

Comment: Try checking out the [CSS docs on the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning). They have great examples.

Comment: Added a little bit more explaining.

Answer (score 1):

This is a supplement to @harbichidian's answer

Here is a working example of what you are trying to achieve.
If you want to animate top, left, bottom, right properties of any element, you should change its default positioning (**position** property), Default positioning is **static** and you can change it to say **relative, absolute, fixed** (according to your needs) to be able to animate for example the element's **left** property.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyFLh/2/)

```
$(".leftslide").on("click",function(){
  $(".list-inline").animate({left:'-=250px'}, 300);   
});

ul{width:22222px; position:relative}
```